# Incompatible encodings even when two strings are exactly of same encoding

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to append content from a file to a string.

opening the file using iso-8859-1 encoding and setting the string to same encoding.

but when trying to concatenate values I get a `incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)`  error.

why this happen if both strings are of same encoding?

actually I have no UTF-8 strings there.

```
sql = "
INSERT INTO pages
(meta_title, meta_description, meta_keywords, title, URL, content)
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');
".force_encoding('iso-8859-1') # setting string to iso-8859-1

Dir['./*'].select { |e| File.file? e }.each do |e|
  f = File.open(e, "r:iso-8859-1") # opening the file using iso-8859-1
  # extracting meta, title etc
  puts sql % [*meta, title, url, content]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use explicit encoding on extracted content as well.

Like this:

```
puts sql % [*meta, title, url, content].map { |s| s.force_encoding('iso-8859-1') }
```

Comment: Blindly calling force_encoding is a dangerous business

Comment: works, importer started, 100+ files so far without any issues. thank you.

Comment: I'd double check you don't get garbage  data when the file being read contains non ascii characters

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a file there are 2 encodings: the external encoding and the internal encoding.

The external encoding deals with the actual data on disk: ruby will use that encoding to interpret bytes retrieved from the file and will convert any bytes written to that encoding.

Internal encoding affects what is returned when you do `f.read`. If the internal encoding is non nil and different to the external encoding ruby will transcode the file as you read it. By default `Encoding.default_internal` is used, I assume this must be UTF-8 on your system with the result that ruby is reading your file as iso-8859-1 but then transcoding to utf-8 before returning the data to you.

Depending on the larger environment you are operating in you could either change the value of `Encoding.default_internal` or explicitly set what internal encoding you want:

```
File.open(e, "r:iso-8859-1:iso-8859-1")
```

James Gray has a [blog post](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) on this (and in fact a whole series on ruby's string encoding stuff)

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention i did try both `File.open(e, "r:iso-8859-1:iso-8859-1")` and File.open(e, "r:iso-8859-1"), neither works

Comment: In which case the problem could be at how you extract meta, title, url etc.

Comment: could be Nokogiri convert it in UTF